# Writing with multiple psql processes to database seems to damage data

Tags: postgresql, import, postgresql-8.4

I have a couple terabytes of CSV data that I am trying to import into a PostgreSQL 8.4 database (on a RedHat 6.2 server), whose data directory is initialized on a multipath hardware RAID. There are four folders of CSV data that need to be imported, and the import script acts according to what it finds in those directories, so right now it's simplest for me to run the import script separately for each server.

I have run these scripts serially on a Debian server (without multipath) before, waiting for each script to finish, and that worked. However, when I had to re-import later on this RedHat system, I decided to fire up four `screen` sessions and blast away. Unfortunately, something I'm doing here is destroying the filesystem (asterisks are omitted names):

```
[trevor@***** ~]$ ls -lah /var/datastore/
ls: cannot access /var/datastore/usersnapshot: Input/output error
ls: cannot access /var/datastore/****: Input/output error
ls: cannot access /var/datastore/localdb: Input/output error
ls: cannot access /var/datastore/*****_DATA: Input/output error
ls: cannot access /var/datastore/*****: Input/output error
total 48K
drwxr-xr-x  10 root   root   4.0K May  3 23:16 .
drwxr-xr-x. 31 root   root   4.0K Apr 22 20:45 ..
d??????????  ? ?      ?         ?            ? *****
d??????????  ? ?      ?         ?            ? *****_DATA
d??????????  ? ?      ?         ?            ? ****
drwxrwx---   2 root   root   4.0K Feb 26 11:47 *******
drwxrwx---   5 trevor coders 4.0K Apr 24 14:07 codez
drwxrwx---   3 root   root   4.0K Mar 14 11:28 *****
d??????????  ? ?      ?         ?            ? localdb
drwx------   2 root   root    16K Feb 26 11:17 lost+found
drwxrwx---   2 root   root   4.0K Feb 26 11:47 ********
drwxr-xr-x   2   1000   1000 4.0K May  4 00:00 trexdata
drwxr-xr-x   2   1000   1000 4.0K May  4 00:00 trexdata_snapshot
d??????????  ? ?      ?         ?            ? usersnapshot
```

There *should* be a postgres data directory here with ownership `postgres.postgres` named `pgsqldb`, but it's now gone. Worse, when I drop into a `psql` prompt to look at the database, the tables are listed, but only data from the first import script has been imported properly. If I stop the postmaster, unmount, and run `fsck`, I don't get that directory back either.

What's going on here? I was assured the multipath drivers and mounts for the RAID volume in question is working, so I don't think it's the hardware at this point. For reference, each script adds about 105,000 points every couple seconds to a table in the database.

Here's the import script code:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                    

# run as: /pathtoshfile/cell_import.sh $(pwd)/data_files in IMPORT_DATA dir                                                                                            

for csv_file in $@
do
    myfilename=`basename $csv_file`
#    echo $myfilename                                                                                           
    i=${myfilename:0:4}
    j=${myfilename:5:4}
    grid=${myfilename:17:1}

    echo "loading grid $grid, i=$i, j=$j from file $csv_file"

    psql db <<SQLCOMMANDS                                                                                    

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE timport (LIKE data10min);                                                                
COPY timport                                                                                                    
 (point_date,gmt_time,surface_skin_temp_k,surface_pressure_mb,accum_precip_kg_per_m2,agl_2m_humid_g_per_kg,down_shortwave_rad_flux_w_per_m2,down_longwave_rad_flux_w_per_m2,agl_10m_temp_k,agl_10m_windspd_m_per_s,agl_10m_winddir_deg,agl_50m_temp_k,agl_50m_windspd_m_per_s,agl_50m_winddir_deg,agl_temp_k,agl_80m_windspd_m_per_s,agl_80m_winddir_deg,agl_100m_temp_k,agl_100m_windspd_m_per_s,agl_100m_winddir_deg,agl_200m_temp_k,agl_200m_windspd_m_per_s,agl_200m_winddir_deg) FROM '$csv_file' WITH CSV;
UPDATE timport SET grid_id = '$grid', grid_i=$i, grid_j=$j;                                                     
INSERT INTO data10min SELECT * FROM timport;                                                                    

SQLCOMMANDS                                                                                                     

done
```

Sample script output:

```
COPY 105408
UPDATE 105408
INSERT 0 105408
loading grid E, i=0135, j=0130 from file /media/backup1/****_DATA/E/0135_0130.****.E.txt
CREATE TABLE
COPY 105408
UPDATE 105408
INSERT 0 105408
loading grid E, i=0135, j=0131 from file /media/backup1/****_DATA/E/0135_0131.****.E.txt
CREATE TABLE
COPY 105408
UPDATE 105408
INSERT 0 105408
```

Comment: You lost me at your first sentence: `I have a couple terabytes of CSV data that I am trying to import into a PostgreSQL 8.4 database`. **Nobody** who has to handle terabytes of data should be dwelling on the outdated version 8.4. The current version 9.2 had its focus on big data in particular. Before you do anything else, upgrade.

Comment: Normal userland apps like your database can't corrupt a filesystem. Check the server logs, hardware, cables, etc. This is extremely likely not to be a problem with your database or script at all.

Comment: It'd also be helpful if you could run your commands after running "export LANG=C LC_ALL=C" (for English output) and *copy and paste the terminal contents into code-indented blocks* rather than showing screenshots. I usually reverse-translate errors in languages I don't speak, but I can't do that with a screenshot.\

Comment: I updated to 9.2 and found that another machine had mounted the same volume on the RAID without using the multipath partition, so I unmounted that. I am importing using one instance of the script at a time and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a PostgreSQL problem.  Damaging your filesystem in that way looks relatively beyond the ability of a mere user-level process.  I would suggest looking elsewhere including:

1. Physical disks
2. Hard drive array management
3. Filesystem drivers
4. Failing CPU or failing RAM

There is very little room for ownership corruption of this sort in the db itself.  Something else is going very wrong at the system level.  Fix it there.

Comment: Yeah, this was the fault of bad behavior on another machine that was connected to the multipath. It was a great learning experience (I can say that now, of course).